# Query uses Index Scan instead of Seek when OR @param = 1 added to WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I'm going through stored procedures to make them sargable and I noticed something unexpected about how the index was used.

There's a non-clustered index on DateColumn, and a clustered index on the table (not directly referenced in the query).

While the following uses an index seek on the non-clustered index that has DateColumn as an index column:

```
DECLARE @timestamp as datetime
SET @timestamp = '2014-01-01'

SELECT column1, column2 FROM Table WHERE DateColumn > @timestamp
```

However the following uses an index scan:

```
DECLARE @timestamp as datetime
DECLARE @flag as bit
SET @timestamp = '2014-01-01'
SET @flag = 0

SELECT column1, column2 FROM Table WHERE (DateColumn > @timestamp) OR (@flag = 1)
```

I put the brackets in just in case, but of course it made no difference.

Because the `@flag = 1` has nothing to do with the table, I was expecting a seek in both cases.  Out of interest if I change it to `0 = 1` it uses index seek again.  The @flag value is a parameter for the procedure that tells the query to return all records, so not something I can hard code in reality.

Is there a way to make this use a seek instead of a scan?  The only option I can think of is the following, however in reality the queries are much more complex, so duplication like this hurts readability and maintainability:

```
DECLARE @timestamp as datetime
DECLARE @flag as bit
SET @timestamp = '2014-01-01'
SET @flag = 0

IF @flag = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT column1, column2 FROM Table 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT column1, column2 FROM Table WHERE DateColumn > @timestamp
END
```

Comment: It kind of does make sense, because it has to scan all over the records to return them when `OR @flag = 1`, even if the `DateColumn > @timestamp` condition would filter some records out (which would use the **index**). And I also think you've answered the question yourself with the option you've mentioned last, checking `@flag` value before choosing what query to run (and I agree it is terrible for **readability**, not sure about *maintainability*), but I don't see any way around.

Comment: Erland Sommarskog wrote a good guide to [Dynamic Search conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html). I'd suggest reading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with dynamic SQL like this.

```
DECLARE @flag  BIT,
        @query NVARCHAR(500)

SET @flag=0
SET @query='
SELECT <columnlist>
FROM   <tablename> 
WHERE  columnname = value
or 1=' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(1), @flag)

EXEC Sp_executesql
  @query
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is with using a variable instead of a direct numeric check. I think the problem is using the `OR` with a **true** result (`OR 1=1`).

Comment: @Radu: yes exactly, 1=1 would be considered as a select without where clause so optimizer chooses index scan, but the problem is if it is (@flag = 1) still it uses index scan. In order to avoid that I would suggest dynamic sql.

Comment: OP mentioned that when `@flag=0 .. 0=1` then it uses index seek. So, only time index scan is made is when `1=1`

Comment: No actually if we explicitly mention 0=1 then it uses index seek, if we use @flag=0 it would be an index scan.

Comment: Thats why @p3pp used two static sql's in his question

Comment: Hi @RaduGheorghiu What @NewUser said is correct.  When I pass the value of @Flag = 0, it still does a scan.  Only when I hard code `OR 0=1` does it switch to seek.  Basically I can see no way to get a seek even when it doesn't have to return the whole table.

Comment: I can confirm that when using dynamic SQL it did use a seek for `@flag = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Your dynamic solution is actually better because you won't get caught out when you pass in @flag=1 the first time and that's what you get for all subsequent calls.  As @RaduGheorghiu says, a scan is better than a seek in these cases.

If it were me I would have 2 procedures, one for "get everything" and one for "get for date".  Two procedures, two usages, two query plans.  If the repetition bothers you, you can introduce a view.

Comment: Thanks @LoztInSpace, I agree that breaking it up into multiple statements does remove the scan.  I've marked the dynamic SQL solution as the answer as I think it's closer to maintaining the single statement in the question.  In practice I have multiple conditions in the where clause that feature parameters, so breaking it up would get fairly complex.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness I'm going to post an option that I just realised works in my specific situation. This is probably what I'm going to use due to simplicity, however this probably won't work for 99.9% of cases, so I don't consider it a better answer than the dynamic SQL.

```
declare @flag as int
declare @date as datetime
set @flag = 1
set @date = '2015-08-11 09:12:08.553'

set @date = (select case @flag when 1 then '1753-01-01' else @date end)

select Column1, Column2
from Table_1
where DateColumn > @date
```

The above works because the DateColumn stores the modified date for the record (I'm returning deltas). It has a default value of getdate() and is set to getdate() on updates.  This means in this specific case I know that for a value of `@date = '1753-01-01'` all records will be returned.